# Remote artifact repository vs local

Tags: maven, nexus, ivy, publishing

I'm building few scala libraries and use them in business projects. To share libraries i use 'publishLocal' in sbt. This command uploads artifacts into my local folder. This is ok, it's fast but when i work from another machine i have to republish all this libraries because some changes had been made. So, this my is question: Is my workflow correct? Or i have to publish my artifacts to remote binary repository (ex. nexus) and add it to my business projects as resolvers? Should i use 'publishLocal' at all?

Comment: If you share libraries between servers I would advise running a Maven repository like Nexus or Artifactory.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, it is strongly suggested to use a Repository Manager such as Nexus Repository Manager, or Artifactory.

You might try Nexus Repository Manager 3.x, as it should help quite a bit with your problem. You can install it on your server, as well as locally if you'd like as it can be used with other tools such as npm, NuGet, etc...

You can download the Open Source Software Edition of Nexus Repository Manager from this link: https://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype